# How to insert data into a table based on conditions in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table1

```
Date        Sec_ID  Version   value  col5 col6 col7
20131111     001       1       100
20131112     002       2       99
```

I have a stored procedure to insert new data into the table1

so if I insert new date rows:

```
20131111    001   2   111
20130101    003   1   88
20131111    004   1    90
```

table1 will be something like:

```
Date        Sec_ID  Version   value  col5 col6 col7
20131111     001        2       111
20131112     002        2       99
20130101     003        1       88
20131111     004        1       90
```

Requirement: Date and Sec_ID  formed a primary key.
for data that have same date and same Sec_ID, update its version and other columns.
in this case, for:

```
20131111     001       1       100
```

when new data:

```
20131111     001       2       111
```

is inserted

it'll keep

```
20131111     001       2       111
```

only.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [`MERGE` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm). If your table was called `t42` you could do something like this:

```
select * from t42;

DT            SEC_ID    VERSION      VALUE
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
11-NOV-13          1          1        100 
12-NOV-13          2          2         99 

merge into t42
using (
  select date '2013-11-11' as dt, 1 as sec_id, 2 as version, 111 as value
    from dual
  union all select date '2013-01-01', 3, 1, 88 from dual
  union all select date '2013-11-11', 4, 1, 90 from dual
) new_data
on (new_data.dt = t42.dt and new_data.sec_id = t42.sec_id)
when matched then
  update set t42.version = new_data.version, t42.value = new_data.value
when not matched then
  insert (t42.dt, t42.sec_id, t42.version, t42.value)
  values (new_data.dt, new_data.sec_id, new_data.version, new_data.value);

3 rows merged.

select * from t42;

DT            SEC_ID    VERSION      VALUE
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------
11-NOV-13          1          2        111 
12-NOV-13          2          2         99 
01-JAN-13          3          1         88 
11-NOV-13          4          1         90
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5a99/1)

The `new_data` is coming from fixed values here, but could come from another table, or as a single row if you're passing values into your stored procedure. The `merge` itself can be standalone SQL or embedded in a PL/SQL block.

If the `new_data` fields `dt` (since `date` is a reserved word, and a bad name for a column) and `sec_id` match an existing record, that record is updated with the new `version` and `value`. If there is no match a new record is inserted.